# Querying Parse Database, to return by matching keyword ignoring its case

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using parse database in my android application, I want to query the database table "candidateDetails" to return all ParseObjects where the column "skills" contains the "keyword".

I am able to get the ParseObject, but I also want to add ignore-case clause in this query i.e. it should return all ParseObjects where skills contains keyword irrespective of the case of keyword.

```
public List<ParseObject> getCandidates(String keyword) {
            List<ParseObject> result=new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("candidateDetails");
            query.whereContains("skills", keyword);
            try {
                result=query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it two ways. First of all **ParseQuery** class contains method [`or()`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#or(java.util.List)) which takes a list of queries as a parameter. So you can create one query for source string as it is, another for lower case and last one for upper case. Just like this:

```
public List<ParseObject> getCandidates(String keyword) {
        List<ParseObject> result=new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("candidateDetails");
        query.whereContains("skills", keyword);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryLower = ParseQuery.getQuery("candidateDetails");
        queryLower.whereContains("skills", keyword.toLowerCase());

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryUpper = ParseQuery.getQuery("candidateDetails");
        queryUpper.whereContains("skills", keyword.toUpperCase());

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> queryCombined = ParseQuery.or(Arrays.asList(query, queryLower, queryUpper));

        try {
            result=queryCombined.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
}
```

Also you can use method [`whereMatches(String key, String regex, String modifiers)`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereMatches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) and one of the possible modifiers is `i` which means `ignore case`. So you can modify your query as follows:

```
public List<ParseObject> getCandidates(String keyword) {
        List<ParseObject> result=new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("candidateDetails");
        String pattern = "^.*" + keyword + ".*$";
        query.whereMatches("skills", keyword, "i");
        try {
            result=query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: What is the use of String pattern = "^.*" + keyword + ".*$"; in the second method?

Comment: It is regexp pattern to check whether string contains substring

Comment: I think whereMatches clause already checks substring, so we don't need to use regex.

Comment: worth trying. Tried with pattern - it works, without pattern - didn't try

Comment: @OlegOsipenko Thank you very much for this simple solution. By the way there is no need to check patterns, it works fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

Some answers on the Parse forums say that case-insensitive searches are not recommended because it is expensive and thus not scalable.

Consider another approach. When you upload your data to the database, add another field that contains the lowercase version of "candidateDetails." Then query that field using a lowercase version of your keyword.

Comment: yeah, we're using this way: we have cloud script that automatically converts strings in some columns to lowercase